# Virtual Machine domain name

Tags: virtual-machine, dns, virtualization, domain-name

I'm starting to learn self-hosting, and I now have a dedicated server at one supplier (So You Start) and a domain name bought at another (OVH).

On my dedicated server, I have a Proxmox VE installation with a few VM. I want my domain to point at my VM, and then to be able to set a subdomain for each apps that I installed on my vm (like cloud.mydomain.com for NextCloud, news.mydomain.com for TinyTinyRSS...).

I basically don't know how to do this, and I'm lost with understanding what exactely are DNS Server, DNS Zones... Is their a clear, beginner-oriented explanation on how all this works, theoreticaly, and any clue on how to practicaly achieve this ?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A zone is your entire domain name space - *.example.com, including example.com itself.

Each zone has records that relate to host names and their IP addresses (A records or CNAME records), and other DNS functions like what servers are responsible for the names in the zone (NS records), what servers should receive mail for the zone (MX records), what servers are allowed to send mail for the zone (TXT/SPF records), etc.

If you want people to access https://app1.example.com and https://app2.example.com then you don't need subdomains - you just need host entries (A record or CNAME records)

A subdomain breaks that down further - so you can have *.sub1.example.com - and can have control of the records delegated to a different name server than the parent example.com zone uses.  In this case, sub1.example.com becomes its own zone, even though it is part of the example.com zone.  So you can specify more host names there - www.sub1.example.com . And, you can specify all the other zone-level records - name servers, mx servers, spf records, etc.

You may also see references to reverse DNS.  This is like DNS, only it is done for IPs - what hostname does an IP reverse look up to?  This is controlled by the person/agency/group that owns that particular subnet.  So your service provider is typically the one that makes those entries for you, either by you putting in a service ticket, them saying "we've set it for what we want and aren't changing it", or by giving you a web form,etc. to fill out that changes the appropriate settings.

Multiple host names can point to any one IP - and any one IP can only point to one host name.  And one host name can point to multiple IPs (round robin DNS).

I would recommend using your service provider's control panel or ticketing system to handle DNS stuff until you learn how to do it yourself.

I recommend reading at least Chapter 2 of this book - http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch2/index.html#concepts